# Как визуализировать данные (таблица с 4 параметрами) на диаграмме с помощью Excel?

Tags: excel, график, визуализация, диаграммы

В Excel у меня есть таблица с данными. Имеется 4 параметра: `Метод`, `Решетка`, `Кол-во линий`, `Точность`.

Таблица в Excel:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это данные по точности распознавания в зависимости от 3-х других параметров: метод, тип решетки и кол-во линий.

- У `Метод` есть два варианта: **Дистанция** и **Число точек**.
- У `Решетка` есть два варианта: **Сетка** и **Круговая**.
- У `Кол-во линий` есть три значения: **3**, **5** и **9**.

Разные комбинации этих 3-х характеристик дают разное значения точности распознавания (последний столбец).

---

Я должен представить эти данные более демонстративно и отразить на графике. Возможно ли визуализировать эти данные на диаграмме в Excel так, чтобы все **4** параметра были задействованы и отражены на графике?

---

Я использую `Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016`.

Залил Excel файл на DropBox: [*4параметра.xlsx*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6tokfnzkz8lzxlx/4%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перегруппировать таблицу, вставить гистограмму
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Также можно сделать с помощью сводной диаграммы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]